# Outlook password encoding for email services (IMAP, SMTP)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap, encoding, smtp, utf-8

I’m trying to make sense of how different mail clients log onto IMAP and SMTP
services. There are the normal ones and then there is Outlook.

Outlook seems to unconditionally encode passwords as Latin-1; when I enter the
password `tösttöst` it logs onto the server with the bytes
*74f6737474f67374*. (Thunderbird is smarter: it attempts UTF-8 first
(*74c3b6737474c3b67374*) and, if that fails, retries in Latin-1.)

The underlying Windows system is set to a German locale and translation
so Latin-1. Hence my questions:

- What determines the encoding Outlook uses for passwords?
- What encoding do other locales use, say a Japanese or Kannada localization
  of Windows and/or Office?
- Is there a simple (as in: non-technical users can do it by following a
  step-by-step guide) way of forcing UTF-8?
- If not, can Outlook be made to fall back on UTF-8 like Thunderbird does?

The rationale for UTF-8 (or *any* consistent universal encoding!) is that I’d
like to avoid blowing up the server side password db with entries for every
possible encoding that customers might be using implicitly.

Comment: Are you seeing this during SASL PLAIN or during SASL LOGIN? The former is required to be UTF-8 by spec (so Outlook using Latin1 for PLAIN would be a bug), while the latter is Microsoft's "whatever we feel like using".

Comment: @user1686: For both login and plain. Even if I configure cyrus and postfix to only advertise PLAIN, Outlook invariably uses the single-byte encoding. FWIW I surveyed some freemail providers. Gmail disallows non-ASCII passwords altogether. GMX allows arbitrary Unicode in passwords; their imapd accepts both UTF-8 and Latin-1 encoded creds *iff* they use the Latin-1 subset of Unicode. This does not however work for non-Latin-1 encodings, e. g. a password containing Greek codepoints can only be used as UTF-8, not ISO 8859-7.

Comment: Even  weirder, Outlook will encode a non-Latin1 password with completely useless codepoints: the string ``töstτεστ`` arrives as ``74f673743f3f3f3f`` … At this point I’m close to declaring it a lost cause.

Comment: So I tried it out and installed the Greek language pack of Office. All language settings in Office are now set to Greek. No observable change. When I enter the password ``ΤΕΣΤτεστ`` for say SMTP, Outlook sends *3f3f3f3f3f3f3f3f* to the server. This is just bizarre.